# Player touch input and continuous one direction movement combination

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create Mmm Finger 2 game like player movement, here is game play video: [Mmm Fingers 2 by Noodlecake Android Gameplay ᴴᴰ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVp08pEXIYQ)

In this player is continuously moving upward as well based on touch, you have full control over player movement. These both things together not working properly for me. Finger based movement also working in all directions still you are continuously moving up.

I have tried to write some code with different ways but can't able to create smooth experience in game play.

Upto now I reached up to here:

```
void Update ()
{

    // checking condition for death
    if (!isAlive)
        return;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
    // executed in Unity editor
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

        //Get the mouse position on the screen and send a raycast into the game world from that position.
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

        //If something was hit, the RaycastHit2D.collider will not be null.
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.CompareTag (GameConstants.TAG_HUMAN_PLAYER)) {
            playerFound = true;
            GameManager.Instance.IsGameRunning = true;
            GameHUDController.Instance.HideGameInstruction();
            hidePlayerName();
        }

    } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        playerFound = false;
        StartCoroutine (PerformGameOver ());
    }

    Vector3 nextPosition = transform.position;
    nextPosition.x += (Time.deltaTime * speed * 0.5f);
    transform.position = nextPosition;

    if (playerFound) {
        Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        //          worldPoint.x += (speed * Time.deltaTime);
        worldPoint.z = 0f;
        transform.position = worldPoint;
        //          transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, worldPoint, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

    }
}
```

Please give some help into this.